# Clustering in pdf annotation like google map

Tags: android, flutter, markerclusterer, pdftron

I'm using [Pdftron](https://pub.dev/packages/pdftron_flutter) in Flutter to display annotations on a PDF. When I zoom out on the pdf, the annotations become overlapping and inaccessible. As a result, I must cluster the annotation. Is it possible to cluster pdf annotations like Google Maps?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no support for clustering annotations in the PDF viewer. This will need to be implemented manually on the viewer side in your app.

If you have any additional questions, please feel free to reach out at: https://apryse.com/contact-us